# How to delete an existing plot (ie. a line)

Tags: gnuplot

Kind of new to gnuplot, was a big fan of xmgrace but had to switch for various reasons.

I am trying to figure out how to remove an existing line in my plot. For example, I plot a line using:

```
plot "somedata.txt" using 1:3 with linespoints ls 1
```

but forget to add a title, or perhaps I wanted the second column, or maybe I got the wrong filename. Is there a way to clear the newly formed line that has been plotted, or adjust these settings after plotting? I am sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure it out/find any info on this. The best I could to was using replot, but (for example) if I adjust the title, it just creates a new plot instead of over-writing the old.

Edit: To clarify, yes I was asking for a way to correct a plot, but specifically correct only a specific line of the plot. For example, if I have 3 lines but only want to adjust one of them.
From the answers (thanks guys!) it seems most reasonable to change my work-flow and load scripts via text-files.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you mean that in the interactive mode you want to correct the plot? I would simply write the same command with the corrections you want in that case.

Comment: In case you want pdf output, I would suggest writing all the commands in some text file and run it using `gnuplot myfile.txt`

Comment: You cannot overwrite the old plot, you will always have to replot the whole thing. Why would you ant to overwrite instead of replot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow with Gnuplot differs from that with Xmgrace. With gnuplot, one way is to write a script file containing    the commands to produce a diagram. This file is then loaded and executed by Gnuplot (with the command `load "filename"` from within Gnuplot or with `gnuplot filename` from the commandline. Adding to, removing from, or changing the diagram  means to change the script file and reloading it afterwards, producing a new plot.

Another way is to start an interactive gnuplot session and to type all the commands in the gnuplot commandline. The     result of a command is seen after a `plot`, `splot`, or `replot` command, none of them overwrites anything - they       recreate the output.

One key concept is the "terminal". A terminal defines the output format like png, x11-windows, ... While some terminals like x11 provide some interactive possibilities, they are rather limited (I only use zoom). You should see your default
terminal as something like "Terminal type set to 'x11'" when you start gnuplot.

Examples for Gnuplot scripts can be found for example here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/